# Invalidating a STS token for a WPF client

Tags: wpf, wif, sign, invalidation, out

I've have a WPF app calling a web-service that uses a STS for user authentication/authorization.  We're using WIF to tie everything together.  We have it all working but the issue we're running into now is that when the user signs-off from the WPF app, the cached STS token still remains valid.  I need to somehow "sign out" or "invalidate" the STS token as well.  It looks like for web-apps, you can do something like this:

```
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut
```

But I am wondering how do I go about performing a "sign out" on STS token for a WPF client?  This has become a major show stopper for us so any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Signing off with active clients means that the client clears its cache.

How do you request the token?